# Is it bad to dynamically create Django views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I wanted to add a generic create form for every model in my app. After repeating the same few lines over and over only changing the model name the DRY principle called out to me. I came up with the following method to dynamically add a form, view, and route for each model in my app.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from . import models
import inspect
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

# Add ModelForm for each model
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and isinstance(obj, ModelBase):
         vars()[name + "ModelForm"] = forms.modelform_factory(obj, exclude=())
```

**views.py**

```
from . import forms
from . import models
import inspect
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

def form_factory(request, form_type, form_template, redirect_url='index', save=True):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = form_type(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if save:
                form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(redirect_url))
    else:
        form = form_type()
    return render(request, form_template, {'form': form})

# Add view for each model
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and isinstance(obj, ModelBase):
        form = getattr(forms, name + "ModelForm")
        func = lambda request: form_factory(request, form, 'core/create.html')
        name = 'create_' + name.lower()
        vars()[name] = func
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import models
import inspect
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

existing_urls = []
for urlpattern in urlpatterns:
    existing_urls.append(urlpattern.pattern._route)

# Add url for each model
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and isinstance(obj, ModelBase):
        name = name.lower()
        url = name + '/new'
        if url in existing_urls:
            continue
        view = getattr(views, 'create_' + name)
        url_name = 'create-' + name
        urlpatterns.append(path(url, view, name=url_name))
```

Is this a bad idea? It feels wrong but I can't think of any concrete reason not to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Roseman's answer is almost correct but with a small error. The simplest way to dynamically create views ended up being:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_app_config('appname').get_models():
    route = path(
        '{}/new'.format(model._meta.model_name),
        CreateView.as_view(
             model=model,
             template_name='core/create.html',
             fields='__all__',
             success_url=reverse_lazy('index')
        ),
        name='create-{}'.format(model._meta.model_name)
    )
    urlpatterns.append(route)
```

The addition of `get_app_config('appname')` ensures that only models defined in the desired app get views created for them. Without get_app_config all models have views created for them, including things defined by django that you should not have views for.

Using `urlpatterns.append(route)` is the correct way to append to a python list. The previous answer results in an error.

I suggested an edit but it was rejected. =(

Answer (score 2):

I can't really see the point of this level of complexity.

`form_factory` works just as well as a concrete generic view, which takes the parameters and is called directly from the URL. The URLconf can then be simplified to iterate through the models and add a pattern for each which passes those paraemters.

Then you can further simplify things by using actual generic views. These can be instantiated directly in the URLconf without any need to define subclasses in views.py. What's more, the CreateView is capable of building a form itself, without any need for defining in forms.py. So you can get rid of both of those files.

One final simplification is to use the actual API for getting model classes: `django.apps.apps.get_models()`. So all you need is:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_models():
    urlpatterns += path(
        '{}/new'.format(model._meta.model_name),
        CreateView.as_view(
             model=model,
             template_name='core/create.html',
             fields='__all__',
             success_url=reverse_lazy('index')
        ),
        name='create-{}'.format(model._meta.model_name)
    )
```

Comment: `apps.get_models()` returns all models in the project, including the default ones added by Django. I would like to create views only for the models defined in my app.

Comment: I found `apps.get_app_config('core').models.values()` but it returns names for each ManyToMany field as well as the plain models. I only want the plain models.