# How to code 'Dynamic' generic based view with Django?

Tags: django, generics, django-class-based-views

I've develop a first eCRF app (project 1) using Django and now I want to make it more "generic" because most of the code is duplicated

I've to make views, forms and templates generic based on available models

I've read some post ([Is it bad to dynamically create Django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294762/is-it-bad-to-dynamically-create-django-views)) with urls config and as_view() override parameters but I need to override get_context_data() and get_form_kwargs() methods so I think I can't use urls config

all my views looks like below: InclusionCreate, InclusionUpdate, VisiteCreate, VisiteUpdate, etc...

How can I acheive this?

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class InclusionCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): 

    model = Inclusion
    form_class = InclusionForm
    template_name = "ecrf/inclusion_form.html"
    success_message = "La fiche Inclusion a été créée."
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('ecrf:patient', args=[self.kwargs['pk']])
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form_name"] = 'inclusion'
        return context
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(InclusionCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['patient'] = Patient.objects.get(ide = self.kwargs['pk'])
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class InclusionUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView): 

    model = Inclusion
    form_class = InclusionForm
    template_name = "ecrf/inclusion_form.html" # nom template à utiliser avec CBV : [nom_model]_form.html
    success_message = "La fiche Inclusion a été modifiée."

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('ecrf:patient', args=[Patient.objects.get(pat = Inclusion.objects.filter(ide = self.kwargs['pk']).first().pat.pat).ide])
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        patient = self.request.session.get('patient')
        context["form_name"] = 'inclusion'
        context["ide"] = self.kwargs['pk']
        context["exist"] = Inclusion.objects.filter(pat = patient.ide).exists()
        context["is_locked"] = Inclusion.objects.get(ide = self.kwargs['pk']).ver

        return context
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(InclusionUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['ide'] = self.kwargs['pk']  
        kwargs['patient'] = None
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user        
        return kwargs
```

Comment: One approach to try is additional mixins, such as `InclusionMixin`, `VisiteMixin`, etc. You can often achieve less duplication with mixins, but you have to be very careful that they don't make your code more difficult to follow. The code you have now has some redundancy, sure, but at the same time it is clear and simple, and you don't want to lose that. It's a trade-off. If you decide to explore mixins, you might want to take a look at the [Classy CBV site](https://ccbv.co.uk/). It is a detailed description and analysis of Django's built-in generic views, which make extensive use of mixins.

Comment: I will read more about Mixin but maybe another approach, if possible, would be to 'autogenerate' all view based on list of model or something like that?

Comment: It depends on how similar the models are. In my opinion simpler is better. I understand what you're saying, but to me autogenerating views sounds like more complexity than it's worth.